# Compute total from array of values by JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of values that I computed the amount per item.

```
<?php
    $items = array();
    $items[0] = array('item 1',3);
    $items[1] = array('item 2',5);
    $items[2] = array('item 3',2);
?>
<div>
    <?php 
        foreach($items AS $k=>$item) {
            print($item[0]." ".$item[1]);
            print("<input cost='$item[1]' type='text' id='qnty_$k' >");
            print("<span id='amt_$k'></span>");
            print("<p>");
    ?>
            <script>
                $('#qnty_<?php print($k); ?>').on('input', function() {
                    var qnty = $('#qnty_<?php print($k); ?>').val();
                    var cost = $(this).attr('cost');

                    $('#amt_<?php print($k); ?>').html(qnty*cost);
                });

            </script>
    <?php           
        }
    ?>
    <div id="gtotal"> </div>

</div>
```

The amount works per row but I want to get the grand total and display it in id="gtotal". how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share the final html generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this:

```
$('#qnty_<?php print($k); ?>').on('input', function() {
   var qnty = $(this).val();
   var cost = $(this).attr('cost');
   $('#amt_<?php print($k); ?>').html((qnty*cost).toFixed(2));
   var total = 0;
   $('[id^="amt_"]').each(function() {
     var val = $(this).html();
     total += isNaN(val) || $.trim(val)==""?0:parseInt(val);
   });
   $("#totalamt").html(total.toFixed(2);
});
```

However I have changed the HTML a little by adding  a class to input and amt and changed the cost attribute to data-cost and  have this now:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inp').on('input', function() {
    var qnty = $(this).val();
    var cost = $(this).data('cost');
    $(this).next().html((qnty * cost).toFixed(2));
    var total = 0;
    $('.amt').each(function() {
      var val = $(this).text();
      console.log(val)
      total += isNaN(val) || $.trim(val)=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    });
    $("#gtotal").html(total.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    <input data-cost='1.10' type='text' class="inp" id='qnty_0'><span class="amt" id='amt_0'></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input data-cost='1.20' type='text' class="inp" id='qnty_1'><span class="amt" id='amt_1'></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input data-cost='1.30' type='text' class="inp" id='qnty_2'><span class="amt" id='amt_2'></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input data-cost='1.40' type='text' class="inp" id='qnty_3'><span class="amt" id='amt_3'></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input data-cost='1.50' type='text' class="inp" id='qnty_4'><span class="amt" id='amt_4'></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="gtotal"></div>
```

Comment: it only totals the last item. the 1st and 2nd item has 'NaN' as totalamt.

Comment: @user2780338 please accept answer if you find it solved your issue :).

Comment: hi! i modified the html and used <table> to have a cleaner design. so i put the input box inside a <td> and the <span class="amt"> inside another <td>. it does not work anymore. it only works when the <input type> and <span> is in one element. what will i change to the script?

Comment: Change `$(this).next().html((qnty * cost).toFixed(2));` to `$(this).closest("tr").find(".amt").html((qnty * cost).toFixed(2));`